# Offset and length were out of bounds for the array

Tags: c#

My code

```
private static int readinput(byte[] buff, BinaryReader reader)
{
    int size = reader.ReadInt32();
    reader.Read(buff, 0, size);
    return size;
}
```

Exception in reader.Read(buff, 0, size);
The exception is offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of source collection

Comment: `if(size<=buff.lenght){reader.Read(buff, 0, size);}`. Else it's to big do something about it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers. It helped me learn a lot about the code that I work on. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Take a step back and think about your code

You've written a method that takes an array of bytes. We don't know how big this array is, but it's controlled by the code calling the method. Let's assume it is 1000 bytes long

Then you read an int from somewhere else, let's assume 2000 is read

Then you attempt to read 2000 bytes into an array that can only hold 1000 bytes, you perform no checking to make sure your array is big enough, nor do you attempt to read in chunks and concatenate if it's not big enough

That's why you get the error you're getting, but as to what you should be coding, I think you need to think about that some more- maybe make the size to the buffer in response to the size int you read, or read in chunks..

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers. It helped me learn a lot about the code that I work on. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The buffer *buff* that you passed into your function to read the data is too small. *buff.Length* should be bigger than or equal to your variable called *size*.

Set a breakpoint on "reader.Read(buff, 0, size);" and hover over buff and size and you'll see what I mean.

Make sure when you call your function, the *buff* you pass in is sufficient size. If you don't know what size to create a buffer for ahead of time, then change your function to look something like this:

```
private static byte[] ReadInput(BinaryReader reader)
{
    int size = reader.ReadInt32();
    return reader.ReadBytes(size);
}
```

Especially since you're just reading it into the beginning of a provided buffer anyways.

---

Summary to frame what you're currently doing:

You provided us a function which takes a binary reader (whatever position it's already at, if it's new, then position 0), it reads a 32-bit integer (4 bytes) to figure out the size of some data after it. Then you read that data of that size into a buffer. You do all of this with a buffer provided called *buff*. You need to be sure that whatever size data you're going to read in, the buffer provided to the function is of sufficient size. If you make the size of the buffer too large, then "*reader.Read(buff, 0, size)*" is only reading it into the beginning of the buffer. So if your intention was just to read the data the way you coded that function into a perfectly sized buffer, I suggest using the code above.

Just thought I'd explain it a bit more in case that helps you understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers. It helped me learn a lot about the code that I work on. My problem is solved.